# how to add short code of captcha in template page in wordpress

Tags: captcha

I have used wordpress plugin captcha and I create contact form with html. how I can use this captcha shortcode in html form. Is it possible to use this captcha shortcode in html form

Comment: why not create a contact page, i mean a wordpress contact "page". Then the shortcode would work. With HTML it's complicated because you would have to copy a lot of code in the html-document because the captcha is probably session based and import some wordpress functionalities (short code usage and so on)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple one;

Save the following code as captcha.php

```
<?php
session_start();        
$md5_hash = md5(rand(0,9999)); 
$security_code = substr($md5_hash, 25, 5); 
$enc=md5($security_code);
$_SESSION['count'] = $enc;
$secure = $_SESSION['count'];
//     echo "--------------------------$secure<br>";

$width = 100;
$height = 40; 

$image = ImageCreate($width, $height);  
$white = ImageColorAllocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
$black = ImageColorAllocate($image, 0, 100, 0);
$grey = ImageColorAllocate($image, 204, 204, 204);

ImageFill($image, 0, 0, $grey); 
//Add randomly generated string in white to the image
ImageString($image, 10, 30, 10, $security_code, $black); 
ImageRectangle($image,0,16,$width-1,$height-1,$grey); 
imageline($image, 0, $height/2, $width, $height/2, $grey); 
imageline($image, $width/2, 0, $width/2, $height, $grey); 

header("Content-Type: image/jpeg"); 
ImageJpeg($image);
ImageDestroy($image);
ImageDestroy($image);
?>
```

save the following file as index.php

```
 <?php
 @session_start();

 @$key=$_SESSION['count'];

 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
   $imag = $_POST['captcha'];
   $captcha = md5($imag);
  //echo "$imag  =  =  = $key<br>";

 if($captcha==$key)         
 {
echo "true";
 }
 else{
 echo "false";
  }

 }
 ?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Captcha Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
<img name="" src="captcha.php" width="180" height="53" alt="">
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<input type="text" value="" id="captcha" name="captcha">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">


</form>

</body>
</html>
```

From the example above, the captcha.php file is included in the index.php file and it will produce an image captcha which is random. If the user enters a correct captcha as displayed in the image, it will return True else False.